# PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

As far as I can tell, my function properly resembles the samples I've seen. Can someone clue me in as to how I get this to work?

```
create or replace function get_user_by_username(
    username varchar(250),
    online boolean
    ) returns setof record as $$
declare result record;
begin

    if online then 
        update users
        set last_activity = current_timestamp
        where user_name = username;
    end if;

    return query
    select
        user_id,
        user_name,
        last_activity,
        created,
        email,
        approved,
        last_lockout,
        last_login,
        last_password_changed,
        password_question,
        comment
    from
        users
    where
        user_name = username
    limit 1;

    return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

if you would like to create function returning setof record, you'll need to define column types in your select statement

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955167/postgresql-return-setof-record-virtual-table)

Your query should look something like this:

```
select * from get_user_by_username('Username', True) as 
  f(user_id integer, user_name varchar, last_activity, varchar, created date, email        archar, approved boolean, last_lockout timestamp, last_login timestamp, 
  last_password_changed timestamp, password_question varchar, comment varchar)
```

(you will probably need to change the data types)

I personaly prefer the types approach. it assures that if the function is edited, all the queries will return correct results. It might be a pain because every time you modify function's arguments you'll need to recreate/drop types aswell tho.

Eg:

```
CREATE TYPE return_type as 
(user_id integer,
 user_name varchar,
 last_activity varchar,
 created timestamp,
 email varchar,
 approved boolean,
 last_lockout timestamp ,
 last_login timestamp,
 last_password_changed timestamp,
 password_question varchar,
 comment varchar);

create or replace function get_user_by_username( username varchar(250), online 

boolean) returns setof return_type as $$
declare _rec return_type;
begin
    if online then 
        update users
        set last_activity = current_timestamp
        where user_name = username;
    end if;
    for _rec in select
        user_id,
        user_name,
        last_activity,
        created,
        email,
        approved,
        last_lockout,
        last_login,
        last_password_changed,
        password_question,
        comment
      from
        users
      where
        user_name = username
      limit 1 
    loop

      return next _rec;

    end loop

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: How does the example define column types?  To me it looks like it's just inserting rows.  And isn't `return query` supposed to send the results back?  Can you please give me an example of how I would change my function to satisfy the requirement?

Comment: Thanks... dunno why that wasn't shown on any of the documentation I was looking at.

Comment: you can also use "out" arguments which kind of work like declaring a type, but you don't have to manage a separate object.

Comment: As mentioned here, you can also defined a custom type and use that in conjunction with json_populate_record to achieve the same thing without plpgsql-

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186033/using-a-type-in-place-of-a-column-definition-list

Answer (score 70):

### Return selected columns

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_by_username(_username text
                                              , _online bool DEFAULT false)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    user_id int
  , user_name varchar
  , last_activity timestamptz
  )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF _online THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      UPDATE users u 
      SET    last_activity = current_timestamp  -- ts with time zone
      WHERE  u.user_name = _username
      RETURNING u.user_id
              , u.user_name
              , u.last_activity;
   ELSE
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT u.user_id
           , u.user_name
           , u.last_activity
      FROM   users u
      WHERE  u.user_name = _username;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM get_user_by_username('myuser', true);
```

You had `DECLARE result record;` but didn't use the variable. I deleted the cruft.

You can return the record directly from the `UPDATE`, which is much faster than calling an additional `SELECT` statement. Use `RETURN QUERY` and [`UPDATE` with a `RETURNING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

If the user is not `_online`, default to a plain `SELECT`. This is also the (safe) default if the second parameter is omitted - which is only possible after providing that default with `DEFAULT false` in the function definition.

If you don't table-qualify column names (`tablename.columnname`) in queries inside the function, be wary of **naming conflicts** between column names and named parameters, which are visible (most) everywhere inside a function.
You can also avoid such conflicts by using positional references (`$n`) for parameters. Or use a prefix that you *never* use for column names: like an underscore (`_username`).

If **`users.username`** is defined **unique** in your table, then `LIMIT 1` in the second query is just cruft. If it is **not**, then the `UPDATE` can update multiple rows, which is most likely **wrong**. I assume a unique `username` and trim the noise.

Define the **return type of the function** (like @ertx demonstrated) or you have to provide a column definition list with every function call, which is awkward.

Creating a type for that purpose (like @ertx proposed) is a valid approach, but probably overkill for a single function. That was the way to go in old versions of Postgres before we had [**`RETURNS TABLE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) for that purpose - like demonstrated above.

You **do not need a loop** for this simple function.

Every function needs a language declaration. **`LANGUAGE plpgsql`** in this case.

I use `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`) instead of `timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`), which is the sane default. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

### Return (set of) whole row(s)

To return *all columns* of the existing table `users`, there is a simpler way. Postgres automatically defines a **composite type of the same name for every table**. Just use `RETURNS SETOF users` to vastly simplify the query:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_by_username(_username text
                                              , _online bool DEFAULT false)
  RETURNS SETOF users
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF _online THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      UPDATE users u 
      SET    last_activity = current_timestamp
      WHERE  u.user_name = _username
      RETURNING u.*;
   ELSE
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT *
      FROM   users u
      WHERE  u.user_name = _username;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

### Return whole row plus custom addition

To address the question added by TheRealChx101 in a comment below:

> What if you also have a calculated value in addition to a whole table?

Not as simple, but doable. We can send the whole row type as *one* field, and add more:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_by_username3(_username text
                                               , _online bool DEFAULT false)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    users_row users
  , custom_addition text
  )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF _online THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      UPDATE users u 
      SET    last_activity = current_timestamp  -- ts with time zone
      WHERE  u.user_name = _username
      RETURNING u  -- whole row
              , u.user_name || u.user_id;
   ELSE
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT u, u.user_name || u.user_id
      FROM   users u
      WHERE  u.user_name = _username;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

The "magic" is in the function call, where we (optionally) decompose the row type:

```
SELECT (users_row).*, custom_addition FROM get_user_by_username('foo', true);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2f85dd6b3314f5d72743b5b8b07cef1d)* (showing all)

---

If you need something more "dynamic", consider:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: Very clean.  Ertx got me to a place where I could figure out the rest, but this is an excellent writeup.  I hope it clears up some confusion for other newbie PostgreSQL practitioners.

Comment: What if you also have a calculated value in addition to a whole table? 

Comment: @TheRealChx101: I added a 3rd solution to address that.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. You're like the Database Jesus around SO man. Sometimes I wonder what's going on in your head hahahaah.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT * FROM foo(params);
```

to

```
SELECT foo(params);
```

In your case it would be

```
SELECT get_user_by_username('myuser', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created `my_func()` which returns `SETOF RECORD` type with a [RETURN NEXT][1] or [RETURN QUERY][1] statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller');
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM my_func();
                      ^
```

So, I set a column definition list just after `my_func()` with `AS`, then I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func() AS (f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT);
  f_n  |  l_n
-------+--------
 John  | Smith
 David | Miller
(2 rows)
```

In addition, calling `my_func()` without a `FROM` clause got the syntax error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func() AS (f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: SELECT my_func() AS (f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT);
```

And, calling `my_func()` without a `FROM` clause and column definition list got [the error][2] as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context
```