# SELECT FROM a function returning a record with arbirary number of columns

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, types, record, plpgsql

I'm using PostgreSQL database.

I've a my plpgsql `FUNCTION` that returns a single `record` with an arbitrary number of columns.
Due to this arbitrariness I would need to use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(97)
```

But this doesn't work as Postgres gives me the following error:

> a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

But if I do:

```
SELECT my_function(97)
```

I can see the expected result but encapsulated in a single column.

Is there a way to fetch the expected result as a set of columns as intended by the function and not a single column encapsulating all of them?

Answer (score 6):

When a function just `RETURNS record` or `SETOF record` (and no `OUT` parameters to go with it), PostgreSQL does not know the names and types of its elements and you are required to provide a column definition list with every call.

**Avoid that** if at all possible and return a **well known (row) type** instead. There are a several ways to declare the return type. See:

- [PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675)
- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

There are quite a few related questions on SO. [Try a search!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20record%20column%20definition%20list)

Answer (score 5):

When using a set returning function (setof) in the select list, on the left hand side of the FROM, the function returns a [composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rowtypes.html). Using a function in the select list can be hard to avoid when using a table as input to a function.

A way to SELECT items from a single column of composite type follows:

```sql
SELECT
  (my_function).field1,
  (my_function).field2,
  (my_function).field3
FROM
  (SELECT my_function(*) 
  FROM sometable) t
```

Or more simply like

```sql
SELECT (my_function('input thing')).field1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here:

1. Return a REFCURSOR and fetch from that cursor in the application.  Note you can actually return multiple REFCURSORS if you need to return multiple result sets.
2. Return an XML document and parse it in the application.
3. Use a bunch of OUT variables, return RECORD, and determine which of these to select from

The basic problem is that the actual return results need to be known at *planning* time so you can't just return an arbitrary number of columns.  The planner needs to know what is going to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return a "set of columns" you will have define a return type as `TABLE` or  `SETOF` in which case you actually return a SET of records which you should be able to `SELECT` from.

For more information about functions returning `SETOF` take a look at [this link to documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html)

Comment: The problem is that table expects a fixed set of columns anyway, so that wouldn't solve the problem anyway, my problem is how to fetch from a function which can't return a RECORD with an ARBITRARY number of columns, let's say one time returns a record with 3 columns, another time  record with 2 columns.

Comment: @flash.tato In that case how do you propose to select anything if you don't know what your output might look like?

Comment: I think that the engine should inspect the RECORD and getting the meta data of fields

Comment: @flash.tato If you define it as such it will but unless it knows to do that why do you expect it to?  You have defined your function to be returning a single variable which is of type `RECORD` which means that to the engine that is exactly how it sees it.

Comment: The problem is that, it could return a RECORD of 6 columns and another time a record of 8 columns, is there a way to select all these columns?

Comment: If the columns are common just set the number of columns as maximum and the ones which are missing the values will have values of `NULL`.

Comment: There are TABLES: A,B,C. Primary key of A is shared among B and C. And i need to select both A and one between B or C depending on a field of A. If that field is set to 1 i've to select B else i've to select C. Obviously B and C have different columns. My function automates this process

Comment: If your table B has 6 columns and Table C has 8 columns which have no overlap.  Make the resulting table 14 columns in which first 6 are populated from B and last 8 from C.  Personally though I would just select that field from A and based on the result get data from B or C using whatever language that you call this function from.  Code becomes simpler to manage and understand.

Comment: I know but this is a didattic question, i mean if i'm told to stick with the current structure how could i achieve this task without making structural changes.

Comment: I mean if i do SELECT my_function(97) i can see the expected result but it is encapsulated in a single column

Comment: @flash.tato Then return `RECORD` split it into fields outside SQL and by the number of fields you can determine where it came from.  But I don't see any diddatic value in what you're doing.  Any software development tools assume that the user knows what they are doing so if you defined your return to be a single variable that is exactly what it is meant to be.  Not a table or a set of variables.

Comment: This isn't the answer i was looking, i mean i could split the returned string but that would need more work from client, while this scenario wants the DB doing the most of the job

Comment: Or i could simply make 2 SELECT query for this task. From your answer that seems the best solution but it was also the thing i want to avoid from start

Comment: @flash.tato The other solution is instead of PLSQL use Perl or Python. But the return should still be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that I follow what you're after, but does this work?

```
SELECT (my_function(97)).my_column
```