# JOIN on set returning function results

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, set-returning-functions, lateral

I am trying to join table and function which returns rows:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, f.action, f.amount
FROM person p
JOIN calculate_payments(p.id) f(id, action, amount) ON (f.id = p.id);
```

This function returns 0, 1 or more rows for each id.
The query works on PostgreSQL 9.3, but on **9.1** it shows following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "p"
> HINT:  There is an entry for table "p", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query
> ```

I cannot move out calculations from function into the query.
I cannot use **JOIN LATERAL** which is a new feature in 9.3 as I understand.
Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Postgres **9.1**:

```
SELECT name, (f).*  -- note the parentheses!
FROM  (SELECT name, calculate_payments(id) AS f FROM person) sub;
```

**Assuming** that your function has a well-defined return type with column names `(id, action, amount)`. And that your function always returns the same `id` it is fed (which is redundant and might be optimized).

*The same* in much more verbose form:

```sql
SELECT sub.id, sub.name, (sub.f).action, (sub.f).amount  -- parentheses!
FROM  (
   SELECT p.id, p.name, calculate_payments(p.id) AS f(id, action, amount)
   FROM   person p
   ) sub;
```

Set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list result in multiple rows. But that's a non-standard and somewhat quirky feature. The new `LATERAL` feature in pg 9.3+ is preferable.

You *could* decompose the row type in the same step:

```
SELECT *, (calculate_payments(p.id)).*  -- parentheses!
FROM   person p
```

But due to a weakness in the Postgres query planner, this would evaluate the function once per result column:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query/18370271#18370271)

Or in your case:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
     , (calculate_payments(p.id)).action
     , (calculate_payments(p.id)).amount
FROM   person p
```

Same problem: repeated evaluation.

To be precise, the equivalent of the solution in pg 9.3+ is this, preserving rows in the result where the function returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, f.action, f.amount
FROM   person p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL calculate_payments(p.id) f ON true;
```

If you don't care about this, you can simplify in pg 9.3+:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, f.action, f.amount
FROM   person p, calculate_payments(p.id) f;
```

Closely related:

- [Record returned from function has columns concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392371/record-returned-from-function-has-columns-concatenated/25392910#25392910)

Comment: Thank You @Ervin  
I did as you suggested:  
    SELECT   
     p.id,  
     p.name,  
     sub.action,  
     sub.amount  
    FROM   
     person p   
     INNER JOIN (SELECT (calculate_payments(p1.id)).*  FROM person p1) sub ON (p.id = sub.id)  
Something like this and it worked.

Comment: @faskunji: Except that's *not* exactly what I suggested. The function is evaluated multiple times per row this way. You can have that cheaper.