# How to match elements in an array of composite type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in, rowtype

Let's say we have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE element (
    pk1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    pk2 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    pk3 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns ...
    PRIMARY KEY (pk1, pk2, pk3)
);

CREATE TYPE element_pk_t AS (
    pk1 BIGINT,
    pk2 BIGINT,
    pk3 BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE collection (
    id BIGINT,
    elements element_pk_t[] NOT NULL,
);
```

The `element` has a composite PK. The custom type `element_pk_t` registers a matching composite type. The `collection` table contains array of `element_pk_t`.

I want to query all rows from table `element` where the PK matches an element in a chosen `collection.elements`, in a single query.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM element 
WHERE (pk1, pk2, pk3) IN (SELECT unnest(elements) 
                          FROM collection 
                          WHERE id = 1);
```

I get an error in the `IN` clause:

> ERROR: subquery has too few columns

However, this works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM element 
WHERE (pk1, pk2, pk3) IN ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6));
```

So it seems that the problem is how to expand the customized type `element_pk_t` to 3 columns that can match `(pk1, pk2, pk3)`.

Comment: Cast your tuple of three `BIGINT` to a single `element_pk_t` (the opposite of your suggestion of expanding the array elements).

Comment: This looks like a really convoluted design to me. You will probably have much less problems in the long run if you create a properly normalized model

Comment: @MatBailie should it be `select * from element where (pk1, pk2, pk3)::element_pk_t in (select unnest(elements) from collection where id=1);` ? but that gives me a `cannot cast type record to element_pk_t[]` error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   element 
WHERE  (pk1, pk2, pk3) IN (SELECT (unnest(elements)).*
                           FROM   collection
                           WHERE  id = 1);
```

Or more verbose, but **preferable**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   element 
WHERE  (pk1, pk2, pk3) IN (SELECT (e).*
                           FROM   collection c, unnest(c.elements) e
                           WHERE  c.id = 1);
```

More robust and avoids evaluating `unnest()` multiple times. See:

- [JOIN on set returning function results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852929/join-on-set-returning-function-results/28853666#28853666)

This works, too:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   element 
WHERE  ROW((pk1, pk2, pk3)) IN (SELECT unnest(elements)
                                FROM   collection
                                WHERE  id = 1);
```

The core of the problem is that **`IN` taking a subquery** knows two separate forms. Quoting [the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN)

> `expression IN (subquery)`

> `row_constructor IN (subquery)`

**Your failing query** resolves to the second form, while you (understandably) expect the first. But the second form does this:

> The left-hand side of this form of `IN` is a row constructor, as
> described in [***Section 4.2.13***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). The right-hand side is a
> parenthesized subquery, which must return exactly as many columns as
> there are expressions in the left-hand row. The left-hand expressions
> are evaluated and compared row-wise to each row of the subquery
> result. [...]

My **first and second query** make it work by [decomposing the row type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) to the right of the operator. So Postgres has three `bigint` values left and right and is satisfied.

My **third query** makes it work by nesting the row type to the left in another [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). Postgres only decomposes the first level and ends up with a single composite type - matching the single composite type to the right.

Note that the keyword `ROW` is required for the single field we are wrapping. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

> The key word `ROW` is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.

---

**Your working query** is subtly different as it provides a ***list*** of values to the right instead of a ***subquery*** (***set***). That's a different implementation taking a different code path. It even gets a [separate chapter in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR). This variant has no special treatment for a ROW constructor to the left. So it just works as expected (by you).

More equivalent (working) syntax variants with `= ANY`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM element 
WHERE (pk1, pk2, pk3) = ANY ('{"(1,2,3)","(2,3,4)"}'::element_pk_t[]);

SELECT * FROM element 
WHERE (pk1, pk2, pk3) = ANY (ARRAY[(1,2,3)::element_pk_t,(2,3,4)::element_pk_t]);

SELECT * FROM element 
WHERE (pk1, pk2, pk3) = ANY (ARRAY[(1,2,3),(2,3,4)]::element[]);
```

Also valid with `(pk1, pk2, pk3)::element_pk_t` or `ROW(pk1, pk2, pk3)::element_pk_t`

See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

Since your source is an **array**, Daniel's second query with  `(e.pk1, e.pk2, e.pk3) = ANY(c.elements)` lends itself naturally.
But for a bet on the **fastest query**, my money is on my second variant, because I expect it to use the PK index optimally.

Just as proof of concept. Like a_horse commented: a normalized DB design will probably scale best.

Comment: @Ziqi: If you have big tables with long arrays, I would be interested which variant is fastest for you.

Comment: my arrays are indeed very long, mostly 10k~30k, all three approaches from yours seems good in my case and all of them are able to leverage the PK index correctly.  And I also tried Daniel's second approach with inner join, but that one was super slow (40ms from your approach vs 12000ms from that inner join one)