# Select rows according to another table with a comma-separated list of items

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

Have a table `test`.

```
select b from test
```

`b` is a text column and contains *Apartment,Residential*

The other table is a parcel table with a classification column. I'd like to use `test.b` to select the right classifications in the parcels table.

```
select * from classi where classification in(select b from test)
```

this returns no rows

```
select * from classi where classification =any(select '{'||b||'}' from test)
```

same story with this one

I may make a function to loop through the b column but I'm trying to find an easier solution

Test case:

```sql
create table classi as
select 'Residential'::text as classification 
union
select 'Apartment'::text as classification 
union
select 'Commercial'::text as classification;

create table test as
select 'Apartment,Residential'::text as b;
```

Comment: please always provide a [mre] please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk updated with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first split b into an array and then get the rows.  A couple of alternatives:

```
select * from nj.parcels p where classification = any(select unnest(string_to_array(b, ',')) from test)

select p.* from nj.parcels p 
INNER JOIN (select unnest(string_to_array(b, ',')) from test) t(classification) ON t.classification = p.classification;
```

Essential to both is the unnest surrounding string_to_array.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to unnest the array:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM   classi c
JOIN   test   t ON c.classification = ANY (string_to_array(t.b, ','));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=635632708be740b058f510a343dba558)*

The problem is that `= ANY` takes a *set* **or** an *array*, and `IN` takes a *set* or a *list*, and your ambiguous attempts resulted in Postgres picking the wrong variant. My formulation makes Postgres expect an array as it should.

For a detailed explanation see:

- [How to match elements in an array of composite type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590314/how-to-match-elements-in-an-array-of-composite-type/69590967#69590967)
- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

Note that my query also works for **multiple rows** in table `test`. Your demo only shows a single row, which is a corner case for a *table* ...
But also note that multiple rows in `test` may produce (additional) duplicates. You'd have to fold duplicates or switch to a different query style to get de-duplicate. Like:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM   classi c
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM test t
   WHERE  c.classification = ANY (string_to_array(t.b, ','))
   );
```

This prevents duplication from elements within a single `test.b`, as well as from across multiple `test.b`. `EXISTS` returns a single row from `classi` per definition.
The most efficient query style depends on the complete picture.