# Declare and return a custom type in PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I found this article:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions

and I'm trying to use it as an example for my function. 
I am selecting different columns from different tables, and trying to return a set of records.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_details_for_widget(widgetid integer)
  RETURNS SETOF widgetdetails AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec widgetdetails %rowtype;

BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (

        SELECT widget_details.id, widget_details.contact_id, widget_details.priority, widget_owner.contact
        FROM widget_details, widget_owner
        WHERE widget_details.rid=widgetid 
        AND widget_details.active_yn = 't'
        AND widget_owner.id=widget_details.contact_id
        Order by widget_details.priority ASC)
    LOOP
       RETURN NEXT rec;
    END LOOP;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the error the the type "widgetdetails" does not exist. In line with the example in the wiki, I changed my logic to look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_details_for_widget(widgetid integer)
  RETURNS SETOF widgetdetails AS
            'SELECT widget_details.id, widget_details.contact_id,      
            widget_details.priority, widget_owner.contact
        FROM widget_details, widget_owner
        WHERE widget_details.rid=widgetid 
        AND widget_details.active_yn = "t"
        AND widget_owner.id=widget_details.contact_id
        Order by widget_details.priority ASC'
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec widgetdetails %rowtype;

BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (

        SELECT widget_details.id, widget_details.contact_id, widget_details.priority, widget_owner.contact
        FROM widget_details, widget_owner
        WHERE widget_details.rid=widgetid 
        AND widget_details.active_yn = 't'
        AND widget_owner.id=widget_details.contact_id
        Order by widget_details.priority ASC)
    LOOP
       RETURN NEXT rec;
    END LOOP;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It gives me an error that says:

> `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$BODY$`

But I can't seem to see / find the problem.

Comment: I found this post and used it as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you tried for the `RETURNS` clause is foreign to Postgres.

Your code is much more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need PL/pgSQL for such a simple function. Use a plain [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) instead:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_details_for_widget(widgetid integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, contact_id int, priority int, contact text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   SELECT d.id, d.contact_id, d.priority, o.contact
   FROM   widget_details d
   JOIN   widget_owner   o ON o.id = d.contact_id
   WHERE  d.rid = widgetid   -- where does widgetid come from?
   AND    d.active_yn = 't'
   ORDER  BY d.priority;
$func$
```

[`RETURNS TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) defines an **ad-hoc row type**. Adapt column types to your actual (undisclosed) table definitions. (This part works the same for PL/pgSQL functions.)

Use a proper [`JOIN` condition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) for better readability.

Simplify your query with table aliases.

Use the data type [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) for `widget_details.active_yn`.

#### Boolean values

I would advice to use `true` / `false` instead of the string literals 't' / 'f' for data input into a boolean column. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html):

> The key words `TRUE` and `FALSE` are the preferred (SQL-compliant) usage.

In a `WHERE` clause, every expression is evaluated to a `boolean` result. `true` qualifies, `false` or `null` do not. For a `boolean` type, simplify this:

```
   AND    d.active_yn = TRUE
```

to just:

```
   AND    d.active_yn
```

Comment: erwin, thanks for the suggestions.  active_yn is boolean.  but i've noticed that whenever i do selects that include this field / column, in pgadmin3 all the results come back with 't' for true.

Comment: @markli: In the data grid you get `TRUE` / `FALSE` in pgAdmin, only results in the sql editor display `t` / `f` for brevity. `TRUE` / `FALSE` are recommended. I added a quote from the manual to my answer.

Comment: thanks erwin.  I've implemented all the changes you've suggested

Comment: @markli: Great. I added another hint about handling boolean columns. :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a custom composite type, you have to create it first with `CREATE TYPE`.

Example, loosely based on your query (to be changed using the real datatypes):

```
CREATE TYPE widgetdetails AS (
  id INT,
  contact_id INT,
  widget_details INT,
  contact TEXT
);
```

Only after having created this type will this declaration be acceptable:

```
DECLARE
    rec widgetdetails;
...
```

Also for the syntax of the `CREATE FUNCTION`, stick to your first version, the second try has serious problems and won't help.

Comment: No need for `%rowtype` in `rec widgetdetails%rowtype;`. `%rowtype` is used to get a row type from an existing table.