# how to call postgresql stored procs from inside another stored proc and include return values in queries

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a postgresql function / stored proc that does the following: 
1.  calls another function and saves the value into a variable. 
2.  executes another sql statement using the value I got from step one as an argument.

My problem is that the query is not returning any data.  No errors are returned either. 
I'm just new to postgresql so I don't know the best way to debug... but I added a RAISE NOTICE command right after step 1, like so:

```
SELECT INTO active_id get_widget_id(widget_desc);
RAISE NOTICE 'Active ID is:(%)', active_id;
```

In the "Messages" section of the pgadmin3 screen, I see the debug message with the data:

NOTICE:  Active ID is:(2)

I'm wondering whether or not the brackets are causing the problem for me.
Here's the sql I'm trying to run in step 2:

```
        SELECT d.id, d.contact_id, d.priority, cp.contact
        FROM widget_details d, contact_profile cp, contact_type ct
        WHERE d.rule_id=active_id
        AND d.active_yn = 't'
        AND cp.id=d.contact_id
        AND cp.contact_type_id=ct.id
        AND ct.name = 'email'
        Order by d.priority ASC
```

You'll notice that in my where clause I am referencing the variable "active_id". 
I know that this query should return at least one row because when i run a straight sql select (vs using this function) and substitute the value 2 for the variable "active_id", I get back the data I'm looking for.

Any suggetions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the full function definition:

```
CREATE TYPE custom_return_type AS (
    widgetnum integer,
    contactid integer,
    priority integer,
    contactdetails character varying
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(widget_desc integer)
  RETURNS SETOF custom_return_type AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
     active_id integer; 
     rec custom_return_type ;

BEGIN
SELECT INTO active_id get_widget_id(widget_desc);
    RAISE NOTICE 'Active ID is:(%)', active_id;

FOR rec IN 
    SELECT d.id, d.contact_id, d.priority, cp.contact
        FROM widget_details d, contact_profile cp, contact_type ct
        WHERE d.rule_id=active_id
        AND d.active_yn = 't'
        AND cp.id=d.contact_id
        AND cp.contact_type_id=ct.id
        AND ct.name = 'email'
        Order by d.priority ASC
    LOOP
     RETURN NEXT rec;
END LOOP;   

 END
 $BODY$
```

Comment: You'll probably need to show the whole function -- or at least a subset of it -- to get any real help.
Is your function defined like "RETURNS setof RECORD" or something similar?

Comment: bma, check out my "EDIT 1".  thanks.

Comment: How are you executing the function? Like "`select * from test(2)`"?

Comment: Quick tip: you can avoid creating a custom type by defining the function as `RETURNS TABLE (....cols....)` instead. Much more convenient.

Comment: That function could never possibly run. You don't define `widget_desc` anywhere, and you don't seem to use the `fmfm_number` parameter either. Is this *really* the exact, unedited code you're having issues with? Or did you edit it before posting and not re-test it?

Comment: Craig, thanks for catching the bug.  I've updated code so it should make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

That's several levels of too-complicated (edit: as it turns out that [Erwin already explained to you last time you posted the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531564/398670)). Start by using `RETURNS TABLE` and `RETURN QUERY`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(fmfm_number integer)
RETURNS TABLE ( 
    widgetnum integer,
    contactid integer,
    priority integer,
    contactdetails character varying
) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT d.id, d.contact_id, d.priority, cp.contact
        FROM widget_details d, contact_profile cp, contact_type ct
        WHERE d.rule_id = get_widget_id(widget_desc)
        AND d.active_yn = 't'
        AND cp.id=d.contact_id
        AND cp.contact_type_id=ct.id
        AND ct.name = 'email'
        Order by d.priority ASC;
 END
 $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

at which point it's probably simple enough to be turned into a trivial `SQL` function or even a view. Hard to be sure, since the function doesn't make tons of sense as written:

- You never use the parameter `fmfm_number` anywhere; and
- `widget_desc` is never defined

so this function could never run. Clearly you haven't shown us the real source code, but some kind of "simplified" code that doesn't match the code you're really having issues with.

Comment: craig, you're right.  this is isn't the real deal.  i was trying to simplify code to basics ... but I will try some of the suggestions here and post back.

Comment: craig, this question is actually NOT the same as the previous.  I used similar code but the concept is different. I'm trying to call a stored proc within another stored proc in this example.  The previous example was just about how to return custom data.  Having said all that ( just to clarify where my mind was at...) I've implemented all suggestions made by yourself and Erwin. The trouble is that I don't think i will be able to avoid plpgsql because I do need to do other logic outside of just straight sql.   I've updated the sample code so it makes more sense.

Comment: @markli Hm, I think you'll need to show a complete example with schema and data (http://sqlfiddle.com) then, since this *looks* like it's just fine as now written. There's something more going on, and I couldn't possibly say what without seeing a complete example of the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between:
    SELECT INTO ...
[http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-selectinto.html]
and
    SELECT select_expressions INTO [STRICT] target FROM ...;
[http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW]

I think you want:
    SELECT get_widget_id(widget_desc) INTO active_id;

Comment: That gives the same results.  Same message in Message window and no results in the "Data Output" window