# plpgsql function: Return rows from a view created from random table

Tags: postgresql, record, plpgsql

I want to create a function that returns rows from a view created from a unknown table(s):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tt_query(text, timestamp without time zone)
      RETURNS SETOF record AS
    $$
    DECLARE

    orig_name ALIAS FOR $1;
    data_tt ALIAS FOR $2;

    BEGIN

    [...]

    EXECUTE 'create OR REPLACE TEMP view temp as 
    select * 
    from  '
    ||orig_name 
    ||' where trigger_changed >'
    ||quote_literal(data_tt)
    ||' ORDER BY trigger_changed DESC';

    [...]--other work on view temp

    --NOW I WANT RETURN THE ROW OF view temp
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

ok I have think (with yours help) this:

Table:

```
create table t(a integer, b text);
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f()
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM t';

END;
  $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

type:

```
CREATE TYPE y AS (
    a int,
    b text
);
```

and now is possible?:

```
select * from f() as y;
```

y name in my case is a variable an I create it in an other function

Comment: How about `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM temp'` ?

Comment: When I do select tt_query(val1, val2) I have:

ERRORE: la funzione che restituisce insiemi è chiamata in un contesto che non può accettare un insieme
SQL state: 0A000

Comment: Run `SET lc_messages = 'C'` in your session to get default English messages for the duration of your session.

Comment: sorry: ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Comment: It works if i write: select * from tt_query(val1, val2) t(int a, int c, ... etc); but I want write my query in this mode :-(

Comment: Please do not change the nature of a question after answers have been given. What you added should be an *answer*. It is ok to answer your own question. However, your answer does not work for several reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tt_query(orig_name regclass, data_tt timestamp)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW tmp as 
select * 
from  '
|| orig_name 
|| ' where trigger_changed >'
|| quote_literal(data_tt)
|| ' ORDER BY trigger_changed DESC';

-- other work on view tmp

-- return the rows of view temp
RETURN QUERY
SELECT * FROM tmp;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Note the use of the [object identifier type `regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) to automatically avoid SQL injection.
- Do not use the outdated syntax `var ALIAS for $1` if you don't have to. Declare parameter names instead.
- I wouldn't use the keyword `temp` as identifier, even if that is allowed. Using `tmp` instead.
- Use `RETURN QUERY` to return a set of records. This can even be a static call without `EXECUTE`. However, you are returning **anonymous records** and Postgres demands a **column definition list** with every call:

```
SELECT * FROM tt_query('tbl_name', '2014-02-15 12:00')
AS f(col1 int, col2 text, ...);
```

This is rather unwieldy.

#### Better solutions

If you *know* the return type (even if table names are changing, there list of columns may share the same types), declare it at creation time. Consider this related question:
[PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675)

If the **return type varies** with the the provided table name, there is still a much better solution. Since you are creating a view with `SELECT * FROM tbl`, you can utilize the well-known type of the table itself as [**polymorphic**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tt_query(orig_name anyelement, data_tt timestamp)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW tmp AS
   SELECT * FROM  %s
   WHERE  trigger_changed > %L
   ORDER  BY trigger_changed DESC'
  ,pg_typeof(orig_name)
  ,data_tt);

-- other work on view tmp

-- return the rows of view tmp
RETURN QUERY
SELECT * FROM tmp;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Simplified Call:

```
SELECT * FROM tt_query(NULL::tbl_name, '2014-02-15 12:00');
```

Also using [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for safe & simple string concatenation.

More details in this related answer:
[Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: @user3297525: Well, good luck! And be sure to report back if you find something. I am afraid you'll find that this is as simple as it gets for varying tables with varying columns.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Please can you advise if I am safe to assume that the temp view will only exist within the BEGIN END block and will not race with other calls of the same function?  The docs say 'per session' but I am not 100% sure.  Thanks.

Comment: @Pocketsand: Trust the docs. Temporary views are automatically dropped at the end of the current *session*, not *transaction*. So that may very well cause problems for multiple calls in the same session.