# Dynamically define returning row types based on a passed given table in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, types, polymorphism, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm dynamically building a query in a plpgsql function that accepts a source table as an incoming variable. I want to return the results of the built `SELECT` statement, which performs aggregations on the given table, and returns results of that table.

However, at the moment I'm getting the following error:

> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning
>   "record" SQL state: 42601

So it looks like I need to define column types of the record rows I want to return.

[I found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611675/24718) where you can bypass table type declaration by providing the table to which the resulting row will match.

```
RETURNS SETOF some_existing_table
```

However, in my case, since the table whose column types I want to match is passed to the function, I don't know the table until I can manipulate the variables passed (after `DECLARE`/`BEGIN`).

Ideally, I want to return the query results (multiple rows) of the aggregation query I build within the function. Is there a way to define result row return types based on a known table dynamically within the function?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to define result row return types based on a known table dynamically within the function?

If by "based on a known table" you mean "exactly like a known table", then **yes**.

SQL is a strictly typed language and functions must be created with a well defined return type. You can fall back to **anonymous records** like you obviously did (with `RETURNS SETOF record`), but then you are required to add a column definition list for every call, like the error message tells you. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_function('foo') AS foo (
          colum_name1 integer  -- name and data type for every column
        , colum_name2 text
        , colum_name3 real);
```

And this is hardly dynamic.

Your question leaves room for interpretation, but *"based on a known table"* would indicate that a **polymorphic function** might do the trick. The return type can be based on any registered row type dynamically, and there is one for every table in the system automatically. Barebone code example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(_rowtype anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
     'SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 10'
    , pg_typeof(_rowtype)  -- pg_typeof() returns regtype, quoted where necessary
      );
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(NULL::my_table);
```

Detailed instructions in this related answer (look to the last chapter *"Various complete table types"*):

- **[Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)**

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_function(NULL::my_table);

How do we execute the function using SQL or NpgSQL command as the type we are passing in, is unknown to the ADO.NET Data Provider?