# Npgsql fetching records from Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql

I have tried to execute the codes below to search for a username

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("search_users", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text, "xxx");

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
            x.Add(reader["loginname"].ToString());
}
```

On the line of `cmd.ExecuteReader()` I'm getting this error

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: a column definition list is
>   required for functions returning "record"'

Am I doing the right way to read the returned records ? This is the stored procedure

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_users(username TEXT) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
      SELECT * from public."Users" as t1
      WHERE t1."LoginName" = username INTO ret;
RETURN ret;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a record that matches the layout of `public."Users"` then I think all you need to do is specify that in the return type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_users(username TEXT) RETURNS public."Users" AS $$
DECLARE 
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
      SELECT * from public."Users" as t1
      WHERE t1."LoginName" = username INTO ret;
RETURN ret;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As far as the C# code...  I see what you are trying to do, and I think if this were Oracle that approach would work perfectly.  In PostgreSQL, the line between a function and a stored procedure is a little blurred (in my opinion), and the easiest way to execute the function and return the results is with a simple `select` statement.  As such, your C# would look as follows:

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from search_users(:USER_NAME)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("USER_NAME", "xxx");

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            x.Add(reader["loginname"].ToString());
    }
}
```

The use of the `@` versus the `:` totally doesn't matter...  I only switched to the colon for personal style preferences.